# Hide 3 digit number into 5 digit number

Tags: algorithms

I have 5 digit number in range 1 - 86400
and 3 digit number 0 - 999

I am looking at combine these 2 (with some logic) with rule length of result should not cross 5 digits.

Should be anble to get back 2 numbers when I need

Can anyone help on this algo?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean more clearly?

Comment: Try out the [PSLQ Algorithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PSLQAlgorithm.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible.  The number of combinations of (a 5-digit number in the range $1$-$86400$, a 3-digit number in the range $0$-$999$) is $(86400)(999) = 86313600$.  That means that any correspondence between these combinations and the set of all $\le 5$ digit numbers will map lots of combinations onto the same number (in fact, the average collision rate will be about $863$).  So given a single number, it is impossible to tell which of the $\sim 863$ combinations produced it.

Comment: I was sure on that and wanted to confirm from math geeks...Thanks